# Swift iOS, UITableView nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Swift (2.2) iOS app (my first) with a couple of `UITableViews`.  One of the views lists payments which are added / removed throughout the life of the program.

This all works fine 99% of the time, but *a few times I have come across an issue where the `UITableView` all of a sudden becomes nil.*

The `IBOutlet` must be hooked up correctly, or it would not work at all.

*What could possibly be causing this when I am not assigning to the `IBOutlet` variable anywhere (just calling methods on it)?*

Or (if I cannot find the cause), advice on best handling when it happens (if I need to recreate it, what about `outlets`, `events`, `autolayout`, etc.?)

```
@IBOutlet weak var paymentTableView: UITableView!


func handlePayment(payment: PaymentRecord) -> Void {
    let existingPaymentIndex = payments.indexOf({ $0.payNo == payment.payNo })

    if (existingPaymentIndex != nil) {
        payments.removeAtIndex(existingPaymentIndex!)
    }

    if (self.paymentTableView == nil) { // Here is where I notice the issue
        Log.error?.message("handlePayment: paymentTableView is nil!!")
        return
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.paymentTableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: You've got to love people who down-vote without bothering to explain why...

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I suspect it is because you haven't provided a stack trace or indicated where `handlePayment` is called from.  The code segment you have shown shows where you check for nil and presumably log the error, but since `paymentTableView` is weak it can become nil at anytime if the underlying tableview is released.  Set a breakpoint, determine where `handlePayment` was called from when the tableview is nil and work out how you got the reference to the view controller & why the tableview is nil.  Was the view controller only just allocated or has it been just removed?

Comment: @paulw handlePayment is called via a web service call (the iPad runs a web server) from a point of sale station; it is called a lot and it is working 99% of the time.  I have not been able to reproduce it with the debugger attached, but it has happened in the deployed version a few times.  The reference to the view controller?  The method is on the view controller and it is the active view controller when it happens.  This is the only app used.  What can cause the tableview to be released??

Comment: It is probably some sort of race condition; The web service call is made but before it returns the view controller is removed from the screen, invalidating the tableview.  The completion block still holds a reference to the view controller so the view controller as a whole isn't released.  When the completion handler fires and invokes `handlePayment` it finds that the tableview is nil.  You can either check as you are now and ignore it or change the property to strong instead of weak

Comment: @Paulw I think you are onto something!  The iPad is running only this app (and it is a small app), so I have not worried much about handling resource depletion issues (yet) and I am not sure why a UITableView would be released while its parent view is active; I need to read up on this.  I cannot ignore the request, since the data has to be displayed.  I have changed the references to strong for now to see if that handles it.  Next I will look into how to respond to low-resource situations as well.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the tableview is being unloaded from memory when the view is disposed of. You likely have an asynchronous task completing, most usually from making a network call, that is returning and calling this function after the view was disposed. I've seen this happen many times when a view is trying to load a network resource and the user is able to switch to a different view before the network call's completion handler is called.